# No error in executing python function but still index not creating in elasticsreach

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I have created a python lambda function to fetch any change-set occurred in route53 and push it Elasticsearch.

Below is my Python function

```
import json
import uuid
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from elasticsearch import TransportError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    mydump = json.dumps(event)
    myload = json.loads(mydump)
    indexName = "routeindexname"
    logstashIndex = indexName + '-' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
    es = Elasticsearch(["192.168.21.150"], port=8200, connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection)
    es.indices.create(index=logstashIndex, ignore=400)
    id1 = uuid.uuid4()
    es.index(index=logstashIndex, id=str(id1), body=myload)
    print("Successly Created - Index: {}".format(logstashIndex))
         
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Successfully exported logs to ELK')
    }
```

Below is my console output

```
START RequestId: c45ab4ff-58c4-47d9-a747-e2af40b02z23 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: c45ab4ff-58c4-47d9-a747-e2af40b02z23
REPORT RequestId: c45ab4ff-58c4-47d9-a747-e2af40b02z23  Duration: 3003.62 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 28 MB  
2021-09-06T13:35:30.809Z c45ab4ff-58c4-47d9-a747-e2af40b02z23 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

When I put `print(id1)` below `id1` it shows in console but when after that nothing seem to be working.
It seems `es.index` is not working.
To verify when checked on elasticsearch Index also didn't created.

ElasticSearch = 7.14

Python = 3.8

Not sure where am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Nothing wrong with the lambda function.

I had to add appropriate VPC, Subnet and security same as ELK stack to Lambda function and it worked.